# Is non-aligned pinned memory allowed with CUDA?

Tags: cuda

Is passing a pointer to cudaHostRegister that's not page aligned allowed/portable? I'm asking because the simpleStream example does manual page-aligment, but I can't find this requirement in the documentation. Maybe it's a portability problem (similar to mlock() supporting non-aligned on linux, but POSIX does not in general)?

I changed to bandwidth test and using non-aligned, but registered memory performs the same as that returned by cudaHostAlloc. Since I use these pinned buffers for overlapping copies and computation, I'm also interested in whether non-alignment prevents that (so far I could not detect a performance loss).

All my tests were on x86-64 linux.

Comment: I would say the sample from CUDA is aligning memory to match a warp size  and avoid performance loss. As you state you don't observe such loss. Perhaps the reason is your particular use case.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't explain why it aligns to 4096.

Comment: Did they hard-code the 4096? If so, the effort at portability fell flat. Personally I suspect `cudaHostRegister` is just surfacing the alignment requirements of the host operating system without any effort to make them stricter or more relaxed. So portable sample code would have to align the input buffer; but that requires platform-specific queries for the page size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Maybe it's a portability problem (similar to mlock() supporting non-aligned on linux, but POSIX does not in general)?

Both [Linux's `mlock`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mlock) and [Windows' `VirtualLock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will lock all pages containing a byte or more of the address range you want to lock, manual alignment is not needed. But as you noted, POSIX allows for an implementation to require the argument of `mlock` to be page-aligned. This is notably the case on [OS X's `mlock`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/mlock.2.html) which will *round up* a page-unaligned address to the next page boundary, therefore not locking the entirety of the address range.

The documentation of `cudaHostRegister` makes no mention of any alignment constraint on its arguments. As such, a consumer of this API would be in right to expect that any concern of alignment on the underlying platform is the responsibility of `cudaHostRegister`, not the user. But without seeing the source of `cudaHostRegister`, it's impossible to tell if this is actually the case. As the sample is deliberately manually taking care of alignment, it is possible that `cudaHostRegister` doesn't have such transparent alignment-fixing functionality.

Therefore, yes, it is likely the sample was written to ensure its portability across OSes supported by CUDA (Windows, Linux, Mac OS X).

Comment: Speaking as the engineer who specified and implemented `cudaHostRegister()`: I wish StackOverflow allowed double upvotes : - )

Comment: @ArchaeaSoftware: Do you mean that cudaHostRegister does not shield its caller from the harsh reality of the platform? All I can see from strace is a couple of ioctl calls, so it's hard to tell what's actually going on linux, and even harder to imagine what might happen on other OSes. Anyway, I think the documentation should make it clear whether alignment is needed or not.

Comment: Yes, I believe `cudaHostRegister` is just surfacing the alignment requirements of the host operating system without any effort to make them stricter or more relaxed. That seemed like the least-harmful path as compared to aligning the input buffer. So portable sample code would have to align the input buffer; but that requires platform-specific queries for the page size. Did they hard-code the 4096? If so, the effort at portability fell flat. The code should query the page size,  would would be platform-specific and make the sample code more confusing.

Comment: @ArchaeaSoftware To express your appreciation, you could of course award a bounty of 50 points :-)

Answer (score 2):

I just found the following lines in the old 4.0 NVIDIA Library... Maybe it can be helpful for future questions:

> The CUDA context must have been created with the cudaMapHost flag in order for the cudaHostRegisterMapped flag to have any effect.
>
> The cudaHostRegisterMapped flag may be specified on CUDA contexts for devices that do not support mapped pinned memory. The failure is deferred to cudaHostGetDevicePointer() because the memory may be mapped into other CUDA contexts via the cudaHostRegisterPortable flag.

and finally

> The pointer ptr and size size must be aligned to the host page size (4 KB).

so it is about the host page size.